# UIWebView no muestra documento .xlsx

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

El tema es que intento visualizar en un WKWebView un documento excel con extensión .xlsx y se muestra una ristra de letras, pero no es capaz de visualizar el excel en la vista, uso este código para cargarlo:

self.webView.load(data, mimeType: "", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL() as URL)

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Un saludo!!!

Answer (score 1):

Con Swift creo que sería algo así:

```
self.webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", textEncodingName: "utf-8", baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! :D